# android- restrict edittext to accept farsi characters only

Tags: android

I want to restrict my edittext to only accept farsi charecters . charecters like ض ص ث ق ف And so on .

I've tried to use xml digit but it did not work .

how can I do so ?

Comment: just a thought [not fully sure] can u please try this 

1. in Your XML put digit attribute (that You've done already) 
2. on Java class, put this two lines editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("YOUR_FARSI_CHARACTERS"));

Comment: Can you post your xml code for reference?

Answer (score 1):

You can use InputFilter for the EditText. [InputFilters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) can be attached to Editables to constrain the changes that can be made to them.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                String text = String.valueOf(source.charAt(i));
                Pattern RTL_CHARACTERS = Pattern.compile("[\u0600-
                \u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u0590-\u05FF\uFE70-\uFEFF]");
                Matcher matcher = RTL_CHARACTERS.matcher(text);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    return "";  // it's Persian
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Use this filter to detect Farsi/Persian characters and restrict them for edittext. Set this filter to your EditText using

`editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});`

This will restrict Farsi/Persian characters

Answer (score 0):

These code can help too:

```
    InputFilter nameFilter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) { // if digit!

                    String blockCharacterSet = getString(R.string.all_fa_words) + ' ';

                    if (blockCharacterSet.contains(String.valueOf(source.charAt(i)))) {
                        edtNameEdit.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.materialWhite));
                        edtNameEdit.setHint(getString(R.string.name_lastname));
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        edtNameEdit.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sPink));
                        edtNameEdit.setHint(getString(R.string.name_lastname) + ' ' + getString(R.string.must_fa));
                        return edtNameEdit.getText().toString();
                    }
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    edtNameEdit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{nameFilter});
    edtNameEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```